Trying to Import Old Database SQL file of 168 MB error TRIGGER command denied to user 'cpses_tey8stquyb'@'localhost' for table
Trying to Import Old Database SQL file of 168 MB  error TRIGGER command denied to user 'cpses_tey8stquyb'@'localhost' for table.
Tried Using SSH too have same error as below
TRIGGER command denied to user 'tejasicj'@'localhost' for table 'wptt_comments'
File is uploaded till wptt_comments table and after that nothing, tried again and again but same issue in PHPMYADMin and SSH.
CHecked the User has Full previledge.
Any Idea on this?
Checked User Previleges all present
Tried PHPmyadmin and SSH both getting Error
PHP My admin SHows  as attached IMage.

"CHecked the User has Full previledge."  "TRIGGER command denied to user 'cpses_tey8stquyb'@'localhost'" Sounds to me like you think the user has ful privileges, but clearly it does not have permissions to create trigger.  Believe the error and question your own results, before you suspect the error is wrong.

Well actually it was an old hosting deleted to new hosting, So trying to upload the backup SQL file from old backup, Previous Username was different as the hosting is new.  Not able to figure out how to sort it. It does import Partial Table but get stuck at WP_Comments table giving error.

your new host probably doesn't let you use triggers.
